# Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined on bootstrap-select v1.13.0-beta

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using angularJS 5 and boostrap 4. Then I added Bootstrap-select v1.13.0-beta to app from here. 
[Bootstrap-select v1.13.0](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/tree/v1.13.0-dev)

I have also made sure that jQuery is being loaded before Boostrap-select.js
[image]

```
<form  [formGroup]="userRegform" novalidate>
<fieldset class="form-group">                        
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="testtype" formControlName="testtype" data-live-search="true">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
 </select>
</fieldset>
<button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: the link to github is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use bootstrap-select in Angular for anything more than a very basic use case, I would highly recommend you take steps to wrap it in an angular directive.

While it is not using the latest v1.13.0-beta, I have an example project demonstrating use of bootstrap-select within angular using bootstrap4: https://github.com/braheem/angular-bootstrap-select

If you are adamant about using v1.13.0-beta of bootstrap-select, you can try a similar approach as done in the linked project, but swap out the version of bootstrap-select with the beta version you are using.